# Can I transfer the game preinstalled in my Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, forza-horizon-3

As of now I have an Xbox One S that came with **Forza Horizon 3** preinstalled, so I have no discs.

Let's say I decide to sell the *One S* and buy an *One X* in the future, can I transfer the game to the new console so I can continue playing it? I know I can transfer the game save data, but what about the game itself?

Would it be possible to just move it to an external disk [as explained here](https://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/how-to-transfer-games-to-your-xbox-one-x/)? What happens to the old console if I do a factory reset before selling it, will it have a copy of the game installation there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as the same account is used on the Xbox one x then you will still be able to reinstall Forza on the one x and still keep the game data.

Comment: So it's the same as if I downloaded the game? I just deauthorize / remove from the old one?